# Programmatically Check AWS EC2 CPU and Memory usage

Tags: amazon-ec2, python, boto

Does `boto3` make it possible to access EC2 CPU and Memory usage?  I looked [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.monitoring), but couldn't find anything in the docs.

How do I programmatically check memory and CPU usage on an EC2 server running Windows 2012? (preferably with python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CloudWatch to monitor CPU usage, the [Boto2 CloudWatch Description](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/cloudwatch_tut.html) shows how to access the metrics.

For memory usage you need some kind of check or agent running inside the VM.

Comment: here are the boto3 cloudwatch docs http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html